# How do I configure GTM to track only successful sign-ups on this site?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Given that I want to track successful sign-ups

When I set up in Google Tag Manager:
Trigger type: Click - All Elements
Trigger fires on: click classes contain "ht-app__form-submit"

Then my trigger fires any time someone hits the "Sign button" on this page
https://www.myhometouch.com/app/register

OK.
However, I only want to track the clicks where the sign-up was successful, so I want to "check validation" but this creates two questions for me:
1. With trigger type "All Elements" you cannot enter a validation, but if I select the other option "Click - Just Links", then my Google Tag Manager debugger shows that my Tags are not firing anymore. So which event type do I need to set up in GTM?
2. After I find the right event, what would be the correct "check validation" to enter to make sure only successful sign-ups are counted? Would it be Click URL with some value? Any insight in this would be much appreciated.

many thanks

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNTNg.png)

Comment: Hey @eian you already solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I would push an event to dataLayer after the successfully validation (supposing you have access to the project code files where the validation is made)

```
dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
    'event' : 'signupEvent',
  });
```

And then I'd use that event to create a **custom trigger** to fire the desired Tag

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms and links (references) are two diffent type of things. Your form is not a link, so this is not the right path.

You also don't need the explicit click tracking but the form submission tracking. Select the trigger "form submit". Then check the box "check validation". In the next drop down you can select the variable "Click Classes". This one should contain the value of your form class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer, but I already tried this. When I choose the trigger "form submit", the tag doesn't fire at all...

Comment: Your form probably is using some JavaScript to extend the form capabilities. This way the GTM form validation doesn't work, because it expects a standard form with no extras. However your form probably bypass the generic form submits. So you also cant use the generic form validation in GTM. Then you should try to track the conversion on the confirmation page or just the click withouth validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable in Google Tag Manager that checks if the Login Form input texts are filled (not empty) and then, pass this variable to the trigger and set it to fire only if fileds are not empty.

Please find an example in these screenshots:

[GTM variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW3lX.png)

[GTM trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2YeY.png)

Hope this was helpful !